# Call show on array of jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a little problem concerning performance of `jQuery.show`.
This problem occurs in IE8 (probably also versions below, but IE8 is of my interest).

I have an array of jQuery objects, lets call it `elements`.
I want to show them, so i did:

```
for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    elements[i].show();
}
```

The bottleneck seems to be the call to `show`. The array is already generated, so that takes no time. looping through an array should not be a problem either.

I thought of reducing this to one call to `show` by creating a new jQuery element containing all my elements. but I was not sure how to do this. I tried by `jQuery.add`.

```
var $elements = elements[0];
for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
     $elements = $elements.add(elements[i]);
}
$elements.show();
```

Now, this time it seems to be a problem with `jQuery.add`. Probably because it always creates a new object.

So, I thought of three different approaches that could solve my problem. Maybe you can help me with one of them:

- Is there a jQuery method like `add` that does not return a new object, but instead adds it to the current jQuery element?
- Is there an easy and fast way to create a jQuery element by an array of jQuery elements?
- Is there a way to `show` all jQuery objects in an array in a faster way?

Answering just one of the question would probably help me out here. My problem is, that jquery always expects an array of `DOM elements` and not an array of `jQuery elements` in its methods.

Thanks a lot in advance!

-- EDIT about the contents of `elements`

I have a jstree that dynamically creates nodes (that is, `li` elements). These elements have an attribute `data-id` to identify them.
Now, I could always query for something like $('li[data-id=xxx]'), but this would be very slow. So instead, when `li` elements are created, i cache them into a dictionary like object (key is the data-id, value is the node). Out of this object, i generate my array `elements`. This happens very fast.
The array can have a size of up to 4000 nodes. Every jQuery Element in the array only contains one DOM-Element (`li`).

Comment: Maybe you want to add all those elements to a div (or similar) and then show the div?

Comment: @alexandernst at first glance, this could get complicated in my situation because they are part of a `jstree`. I will keep the suggestion in mind though, maybe i will try it when i get no other ideas. thanks!

Comment: Could you show us the contents of `elements`?

Comment: @Chips You habe to add these elements to the DOM tree. The browser shows only the node there. Javascriptvariables contains just a couple of bits. So I think the idea from alex is a good way.

Comment: Also note that using ```.show()``` and ```.hide()``` is way more expensive than using ```.css('display', '')``` and ```.css('display', 'none')```

Comment: @billyonecan i added an explanation about the contents of the array, thanks.

Comment: @alexandernst interesting remark, i will check out how much i can win by that change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

After reading your update, and the comments, this *Very* small one-liner is most likely going to be the answer:

```
elements.each($.fn.show);
```

Using the jQ each method to apply (well, internally: `call` is used) the `show` method to all elements.

---

The easiest, and fastest way to create a jQuery object from an array of jQuery objects would be this:

```
var objFromArr = $(jQarr);
```

I've just tested this in the console:

```
objFromArr = jQuery([jQuery('#wmd-input'),jQuery('#wmd-button-bar')]);
objFromArr.each(function()
{
    console.log(this);//logs a jQ object
    console.log(this[0]);//logs the DOMElement
});
```

But having said that: you *say* `elements` is an array of jQ objects, but if it's the return value of a selector (`$('.someClass')`) then really, it isn't: in that case, your loop is *"broken"*:

```
elements = $('.someClass');
for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
{
    console.log(elements[i]);//logs a DOMElement, not a jQuery object
}
//It's the same as doing:
console.log(elements[0]);
//or even:
console.log($('.someClass').get(0));
```

But in the end, if you have an array of jQuery objects, and you want to invoke the `show` method on *each* and every one of them, I suspect this is the best take:

```
elements.each($.fn.show);//use the show method as callback
```

Comment: thanks, you have put me in the right direction.
`var objFromArr = $(jQarr);` This on helped me out - although it seems so obvious... :D

Comment: @Chips_100: I know the feeling, spending hours and hours, developing increasingly complex solutions while all the time, the solution is staring you in the face... The first time this happens to you, you cry. The second time, you sigh; the third time, you laugh (bitterly). Finally you shrug your shoulders saying something like _"damn, I should've known"_ or _"Why didn't I think about that"_ :D