# hide or show large number of elements using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation in a web application, where based on certain conditions, I have to hide or show large number of div elements, numbers ranging from say **500** to **98000**

.

What I am doing is I am applying a common class on all the div elements and then iterating the whole set of elements to check whether or not they are fitting in the circumstances and hence are shown or hide.

This logic works fine when the numbers are say in the range of *500* to *10000*, but above this range, it is taking quiet some good amount of time to display the result.

I am afraid for really large numbers, this logic may result in some browsers getting hanged.

So, what could be a better approach to handle the above mentioned situation, in most of the browsers

Comment: Reorganize your HTML. Combine as many of those individual DIVs as possible. Group them into larger containers, and show/hide those containers instead. Simplify, simplify, simplify.

Comment: The time is taken up by the fact you are iterating over every item to test if it meets your criteria. Depending on what your criteria are it might be better to give your elements classe, for example, all the elements that should be shown on a sunny day and all the elements that should be shown on a cloudy day (grouping elements that should be shown together in other words). Then you can test the circumstance and just act on all the elements with those classes rather than iterating everything. If that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Blazermonger said, you're getting a poor performance because of the way you're showing/hiding all those elements. Try adding them into a container and showing/hiding the container.

Also, keep in mind that calling show() and hide() directly is more expensive than callind .css('display', '') and .css('display', 'none').

Last, please check [Call show on array of jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930515/call-show-on-array-of-jquery-objects#comment17523295_12930515)

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying a large number of data, it would be wise to use `UL LI` instead of `DIV` with pagination if allowed and you can show/hide them as -

```
$(.ulClass li).toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your problem from a little bit different perspective. Human beings being very complex automatons themselves have physical attributes which limit them to certain rates of consuming information. Neurons in our brain can deliver impulses at certain speed, furthermore, our brains can only contain a limited amount of information at any one time, and so on.

The numbers of elements you are trying to display to a human being are way over the limit of human perception. If any of the divs you are trying to show contained only a single word, then it would make 98000 / (6 * 24) = 680 pages of printed text. If that's some easy reading, like pulp fiction, a trained reader can read this volume of text in about a week, spending an hour a day or so, perhaps even less. There is no reason you should be displaying this much text at once. Split it into multiple pages, otherwise, even if the software will be able to handle that much data, the users will not be able to handle it, and your glorious effort will slide down the drain unnoticed...